# Calling a function name stored in a string variable?

Tags: function, vbscript

I'm using VBScript and I am wondering if is there any way to call a function name stored in string variable?

Here is my attempt?

```
a = "b"

sub b() 
    msgbox "c"
end sub

a()
```

But it always result in an error

> Type mismatch 'a'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like e.g. this should work:

```
Dim a
a = "Call b()"
Eval(a)

Sub b
   ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: @user433531 Please look at the answer of Ekkehard.Horner, `GetRef` is the right (and secure!) way to do it. `Eval` is not secure, uses global scope, is slow and you cannot easily pass arguments in your function. And a function pointer created by GetRef can be passed around as an object, which is a huge pro.

Answer (score 17):

The correct answer is: Use GetRef() as in:

```
Function F(p)
  F = p + p
End Function

Dim FP : Set FP = GetRef("F")

WScript.Echo FP("a")
WScript.Echo FP(123)
```

Output:

```
aa
246
```

Comment: This is a better answer and should be the accepted one.
This method also works in ASP Classic.

Answer (score -3):

```
Dim x

Sub b

 print "xxx"' Do stuff
End Sub

x = "call b()"

Execute(eval("x"))
```

Comment: There is no print in VBScript; the task is to call a function via its name.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?