# vbs using a config file for exe launcher

Tags: vbscript, config, launch

I'm a newbie in vbs and try to make a script starting exe or services with a defined delay between each one
I mixed it in a hta file and it works well.
But I need to use it on many computers and then, need to make this script easier to configure and thought to add a config file .csv.
But I don't success to make my script reading all the lines of my csv one after the other.

My script working:

```
<!-- ----- ExeScript Options Begin -----  ScriptType: window,invoker  DestDirectory: temp  Icon:
     C:\Users\stream\Desktop\startapp.bmp  File:
     C:\Users\stream\Desktop\startapp.bmp  OutputFile:
     C:\Users\stream\Desktop\test.exe  ----- ExeScript Options End -----
     -->

    <head>
    <title>Start App</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
      APPLICATIONNAME="Start App"
      ID="startapp"
      VERSION="1.3"
      MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
      ICON="startapp.ico"
      SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
      SELECTION="no"/>

    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    window.resizeTo(350,275);
    window.moveTo(2,720);
    </SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT language="vbscript">
    Dim WshShell

    Sub Window_onLoad
        StartTimer      
    End Sub

    Sub StartTimer
        MonTimer0 =window.setTimeOut ("welcome", 5000, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript
        MonTimer1 = window.setTimeOut ("Start01", 35000, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript 
        MonTimer2 = window.setTimeOut ("Start02", 45000, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript 
        MonTimer8 = window.setTimeOut ("Startend", 55000, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript 
        MonTimer9 = window.setTimeOut ("Startclose", 65000, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript 
    End sub

    Sub Welcome
    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (""Vos applications vont se lancer dans un instant... Veuillez patienter..."")", 100)
    End Sub     

    Sub Start01
    Set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\soft1\soft1.exe"""
    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (""soft1 a bien été lancé !"")", 100)
    End Sub

    Sub Start02
    Set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\soft2\soft2.exe"""
    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (""Soft2 a bien été lancé !"")", 100)
    End Sub

    Sub Startend
    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (""Toutes les applications ont été correctement lancées ! StartApp va se fermer..."")", 100)
    End Sub

    Sub Startclose
    window.close()
    End Sub

    Set WshShell = nothing

    </SCRIPT>

    </head>

    <Body STYLE="font:10 pt arial; color:white;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#000033', EndColorStr='#0000FF')">

    <p><center> <img src=".\startapp.bmp" /> </center></p>
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <p><center>
    <span style="color:white">
    <div id = D></div>

    <script language = vbs>
    Sub MaSub (E)
    Document.All.D.innerHTML = E
    ClearTimeOut S
    End Sub
    </script>
    </center></p>

    </span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now the code I'm trying to make...
csv file:

```
    MonTimer0;Start01;5000;"C:\Program Files\soft1\soft1.exe";soft1 a bien été lancé !
    MonTimer1;Start02;10000;"C:\Program Files\soft1\soft2.exe";soft2 a bien été lancé !;
```

hta file:

```
    <!-- ----- ExeScript Options Begin -----
     ScriptType: window,invoker
     DestDirectory: temp
     Icon: D:\Bureau\startapp.bmp
     File: D:\Bureau\startapp.bmp
     OutputFile: D:\Bureau\test.exe
     ----- ExeScript Options End ----- -->

    <head>
    <title>Start App</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
      APPLICATIONNAME="Start App"
      ID="startapp"
      VERSION="1.2"
      MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
      ICON="startapp.ico"
      SCROLL="no"
      SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
      SELECTION="no"/>

    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    window.resizeTo(350,275);
    window.moveTo(10,10);
    </SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT language="vbscript">
      Dim FSO, LeFichier
                Dim CheminNomFichier, MeTbl, PourTbl, T


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    CheminNomFichier =  "D:\Mes documents\PROGRAMMATION\Startapp\StartApp.csv"
    Set LeFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(CheminNomFichier,1)

    PourTbl = LeFichier.ReadAll

    LeFichier.Close

       Dim Var0, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4
    ' .......................
    'PourTbl contient: "un;deux;trois;quatres;cinqiéme et dernier;"
        MeTbl = split(PourTbl,";")
        for T =0 to ubound(MeTbl)-1

        next
        var0 = MeTbl(0)
        var1 = MeTbl(1)
        var2 = MeTbl(2)
        var3 = MeTbl(3)
var4 = MeTbl(4)

    Dim WshShell

            Sub Window_onLoad
                StartTimer      
            End Sub

    Sub StartTimer
                var0 =window.setTimeOut ( var1 , var2, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript
            End sub

    Sub var1

    Set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(var3)

    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (var4)", 100)
    End Sub

    Sub Startend
    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (""toutes les applications ont été correctement lancées !"")", 100)
    End Sub

    Sub Startend
    window.close()
    End Sub

    Set WshShell = nothing 
    </SCRIPT>

    </head>

    <Body STYLE="font:10 pt arial; color:white;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#000033', EndColorStr='#0000FF')">

    <p><center> <img src=".\startapp.bmp" /> </center></p>
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <p><center>
    <span style="color:white">
    <div id = D></div>

    <script language = vbs>
    Sub MaSub (E)
    Document.All.D.innerHTML = E
    ClearTimeOut S
    End Sub
    </script>
    </center></p>

    </span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

running the hta it tells me syntax error on line 68 [ sub (var1) ]
and does nothing...

If you could help me, it would be very kind !
nb: I'm sorry if my English is a bit bad, it's a long time I didn't use this language.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set LeFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(CheminNomFichier,1)
PourTbl = LeFichier.ReadAll
LeFichier.Close
...
MeTbl = split(PourTbl,";")
```

The above is most likely what causes your problem that the HTA seems to not read all lines. If you read the entire CSV at once (`ReadAll`) you **must** split the text into lines before you split each line into separate fields:

```
Set LeFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(CheminNomFichier,1)
PourTbl = LeFichier.ReadAll
LeFichier.Close
...
For Each line In Split(PourTbl, vbNewLine)
  MeTbl = split(PourTbl,";")
  var0 = MeTbl(0)
  ...
Next
```

Otherwise you have to read the file line by line:

```
Set LeFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(CheminNomFichier,1)
...
Do Until LeFichier.AtEndOfStream
  PourTbl = LeFichier.ReadLine
  MeTbl = split(PourTbl,";")
  var0 = MeTbl(0)
  ...
Next
LeFichier.Close
```

Either way, you need to process the lines of the file in a loop.

Another issue is that the loop you have in your code

```
MeTbl = split(PourTbl,";")
for T =0 to ubound(MeTbl)-1

next
var0 = MeTbl(0)
var1 = MeTbl(1)
...
```

doesn't actually do anything. You split the content of the CSV, then increment T up to `UBound(MeTbl)-1` without doing anything else, then assign the first 5 values (i.e. the values from the first line of the CSV) to variables.

Comment: Shouldn't `For Each line In Split(PourTbl)` be `For Each line In Split(PourTbl, vbCrLf)`?

Comment: I prefer `vbNewLine`, but yes. Fixed.

Comment: Hello! Could you have a look to my last code (24th, May), please?My script is running but all exe files are started at the same time instead of starting with the wanted delay.Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: Hello Ansgar Wiechers![I'm going on, even if all isn't perfect... From the one hand]....(answered May 24 at 12:35)    all is running but at the wrong time...all exe are launched at the same time and the delays and texts are displayed after

Comment: @odelh Your answer from May 24 was deleted by a moderator. That means it's no longer visible to anyone who doesn't have access to moderator tools. Why didn't you post it as a new question like I asked you?

Comment: Oh.ok.I apologized, I hadn't understood that way, because on my way I still can see my answer.   Then I'll create a new question.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable **and** a sub named `var1`. (And you shouldn't use such lousy names in the first place.)

Comment: Hello Ekkehard.Horner !First, why shouldn't I use this kind of name?Then, What is the way to name my sub with the variable's text ?Thank you

Comment: @odelh Names should be meaningful, "var1" etc aren't. If you want to call a function by a name provided at run-time, use GetRef() as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13127606/603855

Comment: I re wrote my code... It runs better but with many errors.but I have to wait 8 hours to post it 'cause it's to long for posting it in comments.btw I looked at your link and it will help me in many cases.